# Python 2.7 - Send multiple requests to server Without getting blocked (DOS)

Tags: windows, python-2.7, web-scraping, youtube, denial-of-service

My WebScraper uses **urllib** to get data from sites like YouTube. But I often run into a problem when there are too many requests, resulting in the site blocking my connection.
So my question is, is there a way, in Python, to bypass this?
Such as changing the IP address (via some native Socket module, or **os.system**("some command like netsh"), a simple **API** that doesn't require authentication (like oAuth or a Key), or simply using a web-based proxy to divert my traffic?

```
search_url = "https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query="  #Search URL
bypass_url = "https://someProxy.com/url=" + search_url
for video_ID in raw_video_list:
    raw_html = self.ReadHTML( search_url + video_ID )  #Returns raw HTML
    # Then the program does it's magic with that html
```

That is just a basic idea of the program, but it'll iterate a block like that over a hundred times.

Using Python 2.7, Windows 8, native modules

Comment: why not use the youtube api to get results... it usually is lighter weight and allows more requests

Comment: Attempting to bypass network security mechanisms is liable to get you in worse trouble, e.g., arrested.  You need to either slow down your requests to an acceptable rate, or use officially sanctioned methods as @Miltox suggests.

Comment: @MiltoxBeyond I've thought about it, but found it more complicated because it's not just Youtube I'm using, and I was also just curious if there was a way to setup a Bot Network or something to bypass this. Curious really...

Comment: @HarryJohnston Haven't thought much about the legality or repercussions ... I'll have to keep this in mind, thanks!

Comment: @ChrisNguyen you can use a proxy service